# Flash compiler arguments - force SWC inclusion

Tags: flash, apache-flex, compiler-construction, fdt

I'm trying to write a compiler argument for FDT to force the inclusion of one of my SWCs.  It looks kind of like this (App name changed, but the real one also contains mixed case and a space):

```
-include-libraries "C:\Workspaces\My App\libs\site.swc"
```

Problem is that the compiler claims it is unable to open this file.  Is there a problem maybe with using a full path like this? Ideally I would prefer to use a token to represent the project folder, something like `-include-libraries "${project}/libs/site.swc"`, but I don't seem able to find a token list in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt understand which tool you are using to compile flex If you are using

**ANT**
this link is useful  [Working with compiler options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_4.html)

for **Command Line Compiler** option see this [About the application compiler options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html)

and for **Flex/Flash builder** you can include lib from project propertied

**Properties>>Flex Build Path>>Library Path**

EDITED for **Command Line Compiler**

You can use  [configuration files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_09.html#138195) for command-line utilities and bulider

using these files you can define custom [tokens](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_09.html#138195) like  ${flexlib}

and for Tokens in services-configuration files see [About configuration files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/lcds/help.html?content=lcarch_4.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: I'm using FDT and have included my SWC as a linked library so it is included in the build, but that will only include the classes from the SWC that are referenced in code.  I want to force the inclusion of the entire SWC via the compiler arguments as mentioned be Cameron Yule here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023205/as3-embed-or-import-all-classes-in-an-external-swf-without-referencing-each-class

Comment: The command I'm using is listed in your second link, but I can't get it to work in FDT.

Comment: what i get is that use need a custom token for relative path. Plz see edited contents